# Electron Printing Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, electron

Whenever I am trying to use the webContents.print(options,())  I am getting the same error message  "Printer: print_view_manager_base.cc:352 Printer settings invalid for Canon G1010 series (destination type kLocal): content size is empty; page size is empty; printable area is empty".
Though the options object is appropriate.[PRINTER OPTIONS OBJECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Js4.png)
[ERROR MASSAGE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhI3S.png)

Tried filling up the options as per the error massage but no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.